# How to generate desired size (example 8096) long bit hash codes - c#

Tags: c#, hash, bit, string-hashing

There are many hashing methods but I want to compose bit hash with 8096 bits long. Is it possible to achieve this?

For example when I enter "House" I should get a string like:

```
"0101010001010101..." (8096 bits)
```

How can i achieve this (using C# 4.0 is ok)?

If you wonder why I need such thing, I need it for comparing Signature Files & Vector Space Model.

Comment: what does "Signature files & vector space model" mean?

Comment: I don't think .NET has any such large hashes built in. Are you certain you actually need hashes this large?

Comment: they are topic at information retrieval

Comment: @CoryNelson well if possible yes. Do you know maximum size bit hashing possible ?

Comment: SHA-512 is the largest .NET supports.

Comment: @CoryNelson can i convert it to bits ?

Comment: Well, everything is made up of bits? So I'm not sure what you're asking. SHA-512 creates a hash that is 512 bits long.

Comment: Everything should be bit 0 & 1

Comment: Ok i converted SHA-512 and yes it generated binary 512 bit code. But 512 hashing really would not solve my problem :D

Comment: Maybe i can use sha256+sha384+sha512 yes this is a pretty good idea :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21921/discussion-between-monstermmorpg-and-cory-nelson)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fast non-cryptographic hashes you can examine the [FNV family](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-eastlake-fnv-04). By careful and suitable variation you should be able to construct an 8096-bit hash that is reasonably fast.

If speed is not a primary concern but simplicity and quality are then you can simply use a variant of MD5 to make a non-cryptographic hash.

Hash(x) = MD5(0 || x) || MD5(1 || x) ... MD5(62 || x) || MD5(63 || x)<32>, where "||" is the concatenation operation and only the low order 32 bits of the final hash are used, will give you an 8096 bit hash.

EDIT

Here is small code sample showing the MD5 concept:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Hash8096
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static byte [] H8096(byte [] x) {
            byte [] Result = new byte[8096 / 8];
            byte [] Xplus1 = new byte[x.Length + 1];
            x.CopyTo(Xplus1, 1);
            int ResultOffset = 0;
            int AmountLeft = Result.Length;
            for (int i=0; i<64; i++) {
                // do MD5(i || x)
                var md5 = MD5.Create();
                Xplus1[0] = (byte) i;
                var hash = md5.ComputeHash(Xplus1);
                int NumToCopy = Math.Min(hash.Length, AmountLeft);
                Array.Copy(hash, 0, Result, ResultOffset,NumToCopy);
                ResultOffset += NumToCopy;
                AmountLeft -= NumToCopy;
            }
            return Result;
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            byte [] x = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!");
            byte [] MonsterHash = H8096(x);
            Console.WriteLine ("Monster hash in hex follows:");
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(MonsterHash));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i really need something ready to use. speed not very important.

Comment: Well you'll have to write some code. Since this is SO and you are a programmer that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: ye but this is not the core of the project :) so don't have time for that

Comment: So you expect there to be a built-in 8096 bit hash in .NET? Microsoft just called me and wants to know if you'd like fries with that.

Comment: thanks for answer but i don't get your edited answer. only last 32 bits used means what ?

Comment: ok decided to use sha1+sha256+sha384+sha512 = 1312 bit long :D